# HTTP Status Code error When Sending SMS in Civicrm-Wordpress

Tags: civisms

i get the following error in CIVI-wordpress install after configuring and sending an sms:
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
No HTTP Status Code was returned.

I configured the clickatell SMS Gateway following the instruction here:
https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/sms-text-messaging/setup/
Error Deatils from the debug is as follows
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => 
[message] => No HTTP Status Code was returned.
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => 
[type] => PEAR_Error
[user_info] => 
[to_string] => [pear_error: message="No HTTP Status Code was returned." code=0 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=""]
```

)

Any Ideas what the problem could be anyone.
Using Wordpress 4.4.2 with ivicrm 4.6.8

Comment: Is your 'API Type' for your SMS provider entry set to http, and your 'API Url' set to `https://api.clickatell.com`? Is the SMS actually reaching the phone?

Comment: SMS provider entry is set to http and the API url is https://api.clickatell.com but the sms does not actually reach the phone. I find that when  i used the test parameters like is_test=1 and api_id=1234567 it does not generate this error.

When i enter my Api Id username and password and message in the browser  the message gets sent.  

The problem seems to be with civicrm

Answer (score 1):

Check the phone number and see if there is the correct country code.  The code was not adding the 1+ for US/Canada yesterday, April 26th.  See comments on the file in GitHub for a temporary workaround:  https://github.com/PalanteJon/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/commit/ef4e4119b76331ee90bf547044607822907aa323#commitcomment-17262754

Here's a PR request with the workaround:
https://github.com/gah242s/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/commit/aa74097cf66510710b23c22bae5735db59c156db